# I have stored the values of f(x) in an array, but how do i print the value of x of a certain element f(x) from the array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, quadratic

For a homework question we have been asked to **numerically** find the estimated roots of a quadratic equation ax^2 + bx + c, (where a, b, c is given by the user), we cant use the -b formula and we have to use a simple search based algorithm for the assignment. So, we have to find f(x) over a large range of values of x and then print the value of x which gives f(x) closest to zero.

I stored the values of f(x) in an array and searched for the value which is closest to 0. I want to print the value of x, the root of the function, which resulted in this value of f(x) but dont know how, i can only print the value of f(x) from the array which is closest to zero.

For example if my values for a, b &c were 1, -1 & -6 respectively, i want my output to display x = 3 as the estimated root.
Right now my displayed output is = 0. (the value of f(x), the element in my closest to zero)

This is my code:
(also sorry if the code is not formatted properly, im still new to using stackoverflow, any help is greatly appreciated)

```
/*==================================================================
* Systems header files
*==================================================================*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*==================================================================
 * Constant definitions
 *==================================================================*/
#define SIZE 50

/*==================================================================
 * Function definitions
 *==================================================================*/
float array_roots(const float [], int); /*my function where i will search for my root value*/

int main(void)
{
    float table[SIZE];   /* array to store the function values f(x) */
    float a, b, c, x;
    int i;


    printf("*********************************************************\n");
    printf("Welcome to the quadratic root estimator.\n");
    printf("This estimates the value of one root of\n");
    printf("f(x)=ax^2+bx+c.\n");
    printf("*********************************************************\n");
    
    printf("Enter the coefficients in the form \"a b c\"\n: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&a, &b, &c);

 /*populating array and calling function */
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        x = 0 + i*(0.5); /* the range of values of x im using are between 1 and 50*/
        table[i] = a*x*x + b*x + c;           /* to store the value of f(x) at the correct point in the array */
    }
     

    /* Prints out value from the array which is closest to zero
       But i want it to print out the root of the function, x which gave the value of f(x) closest to zero*/
    
      printf("There is a root at: x = %.3f\n", array_roots(table, SIZE));

    return(0);
}
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////*/
/*function outside of  main to find element in array closest to zero */
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////*/

float array_roots(const float table[], int length)
{
    int i;           /* index for loop over array*/
    float root;       /* 'running' root. This will eventually be the root element of the array */

    root = table[0];  /* At the beginning, assume that the first element is the root */

    /* Next, loop through the array. For each element encountered,
       if this element is closer to zero, then
       set the running root equal to this value */
    for(i=1; i<length; i++)
        if(table[i] == 0 || abs(0-table[i]) < abs(0-root))
            root = table[i];

    /* At this point, variable 'root' holds the correct root element */
    return(root);
}
```

Comment: Formatting looks fine. What's missing is some debugging information. Where do you think the problem occurs? Have you stepped through in a debugger to confirm it's performing the correct math?

Comment: OT: Unless you have *very* specific reasons, don't use `float` for floating-point values and variables. Use `double`.

Comment: The value of `x` is a function of the array index `i`.  Specifically, your code has `x = 0 + i*(0.5);`  So, find the array index `i`, then use `i` to determine `x`.

Comment: OT: In `0 + i*(0.5)` why the addition to zero?

Comment: Should you be using `fabs()` and not `abs()`? (And I don't get why the `0-` ..)

Comment: `fabs(0 - xx)` is the same as `fabs(xx)`. The longer version only serves to make you think harder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an expression that turns an array index `i` into the x value:
`x = 0 + i*(0.5)`

To  make this easier, add a function to do this conversion

```c
// Returns the x value used for the index
float index_to_x(int i) {
    return i * (0.5);
}
```

You can then put this function into main:

```c
 /*populating array and calling function */
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        x = index_to_x(i); /* the range of values of x im using are between 1 and 50*/
        table[i] = a*x*x + b*x + c;           /* to store the value of f(x) at the correct point in the array */
    }
```

Now that you have that function, you can update `array_roots` to use it:

```c
float array_roots(const float table[], int length)
{
    int i;           /* index for loop over array*/
    float root;       /* 'running' root. This will eventually be the root element of the array */
    int min_i = 0;   /* index of the minimum root */

    root = table[0];  /* At the beginning, assume that the first element is the root */

    /* Next, loop through the array. For each element encountered,
       if this element is closer to zero, then
       set the running root equal to this value */
    for(i=1; i<length; i++) {
        if(table[i] == 0 || abs(0-table[i]) < abs(0-root)) {
            root = table[i];
            min_i = i;
         }
    }

    printf("The x coordinate for the minimum root is %f\n", index_to_x(min_i));

    /* At this point, variable 'root' holds the correct root element */
    return(root);
}
```

As you can see, this will print out the x coordiante used to find the root.